# Xmodmap error on setting new mod key

Tags: linux, xmodmap

I try to use the cap lock key as mod key.

I have this .Xmodmap:

```
clear lock 
clear mod2
keycode 66 = Hyper_L
add mod2 = Hyper_L
```

and this `xmodmap -pm`:

```
shift       Shift_L (0x32),  Shift_R (0x3e)
lock        Hyper_L (0x42)
control     Control_L (0x25),  Control_R (0x69)
mod1        Alt_L (0x40),  Meta_L (0xcd)
mod2        Num_Lock (0x4d)
mod3      
mod4        Super_L (0x85),  Super_R (0x86),  Super_L (0xce),  Hyper_L (0xcf)
mod5        ISO_Level3_Shift (0x5c),  Mode_switch (0xcb)
```

when running `xmodmap .Xmodmap` I get this error:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)                                                           
  Major opcode of failed request:  118 (X_SetModifierMapping)                                                                                 
  Value in failed request:  0x17                                                                                                              
  Serial number of failed request:  13                                                                                                        
  Current serial number in output stream:  13
```

Do you have an idea on how to solve this?

OS: Ubuntu 17.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's okay that you'll be left without Caps_Lock?
Try:

```
clear lock 
keycode 66 = Hyper_L
remove mod4 = Hyper_L
add mod2 = Hyper_L
```

based on @heymatthew answer to [CapsLock as modifier key for application keymaps](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103814/capslock-as-modifier-key-for-application-keymaps)